# Java: Read data from the terminal using Process()

Tags: java, process, terminal

I'm trying to read the response from the terminal while using a command in with the `Process()`function. I have looked on other examples but I can't get it to work. I wan't to be able to process the data and use a progressbar for example, so I need to access the data when it appears in the terminal. In my code I'm just using the textArea to see if it works for now. I can see the data in the console in eclipse but nothing appears in the textArea. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void unPack(String filePath, String directory)
{
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/local/bin/unrar", "x", "-y",filePath);
    pb.inheritIO();
    pb.directory(new File(directory));
    try 
    {

        final Process p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
        String line = null;  
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
            textArea.setText(line);  
        }  

        try 
        {
            int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The response in the mac terminal when running the command by myself the result is:

```
    UNRAR 4.20 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2012 Alexander Roshal


Extracting from testrar.part1.rar

Extracting  testfile.mkv                                              23%

Extracting from testrar.part2.rar

...         testfile.mkv                                              46%

Extracting from testrar.part3.rar

...         testfile.mkv                                              70%

Extracting from testrar.part4.rar

...         testfile.mkv                                              93%

Extracting from testrar.part5.rar

...         testfile.mkv                                              OK 
All OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do setText you over write i believe. If you say you can see this is working in the console, it would seem with setText all you see is the last thing that it set if this happened fast so it could be working just an empty line is the last thing set. Also it won't read lines continually if there is no data ready at that exact moment. When I've done something like this, first I've used a runtime but i don't see that matters cause i get a process, but i have it in a thread where it can loop until i send quit or it gets a string that means exit or last line because it just needs to loop till its got all data assuming some readline's there's no data.

Comment: Tried to change the setText to `textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\n" + line); ` but it still won't show anything

Comment: do you know that line = in.readLine() ever hits? you say you can see the output in the console but i don't see you in your sample coding printing any lines. I am not as familiar with eclipse maybe i missed something there.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing one of the following:

1. Your `unPack` method runs in the *Event Dispatcher Thread* (EDT)
2. Your `unPack` method runs in a separate thread

If it is the first case, you are blocking the EDT, and this stops your UI being repainted. If this is the case you should call this method on a separate thread, and read the following explanation.

If it is the second case, then you are trying to update Swing UI on a different thread other than EDT. You should handle this delicately. There are different methods for doing this. One of the simplest being the [SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. The problem with Rar is that it doesn't print a line when the proces percentage updates. So you have to read char(s) instead.

```
void setup() {
  unPack("c:/temp/Downloads.rar", "c:/temp/Downloads");
}

void unPack(String Rarfile, String directory) {
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/WinRAR/UnRAR.exe", 
  "e", Rarfile, directory);
  //pb.inheritIO(); //unknown method
  //pb.directory(new File(directory)); // ?
  try {
    final Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
    int line = 0;  
    while ( (line = in.read()) > 0 ) {  
      print((char)line); //remove (char) to see ascii codes
    } 
    try {
      int exitVal = p.waitFor();
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Be sure to read the line: print((char)line); //remove (char) to see ascii codes

The problem is now, how to read the percentage. I have not figured that out yet.